# Android enviar mensagem para vários contatos do Whatsapp

Tags: android, intent, whatsapp, android-intent

Tenho uma aplicação que hoje exibe os contatos da agenda que possuem whatsapp, e lá é possível excrever uma mensagem nessa aplicação e enviar para os usuários do whatsapp, porém quando chama o whatsapp vai sem nenhum contato selecionado, então lá no whatsapp é feito a seleção de para quem será feito o envio da mensagem. Gostaria de conseguir fazer a seleção no meu app, e já enviar para whatsapp os contatos selecionados, alguém já fez isso?

Atualmente essa parte do código é assim?

`Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);`

**Lembrando que deve ser feito o disparo para vários contatos, para um contato eu tenho uma parte do app que faz, mas preciso de fazer o disparo para vários contatos, seria na tela do whatsapp que abre apenas vir já com os contatos selecionados.**

Comment: Leonardo, a resposta abaixo te atendeu ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!

Answer (score 2):

Até o momento, o WhatsApp não ofereceu ainda nenhum suporte para compartilhamento de qualquer conteúdo para vários contatos **simultaneamente**. Em sua [página de FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012), é mencionado os passos necessários para compartilhar com uma única pessoa (que deve ser basicamente o que você fez), mas não várias.

Comment: Além disso tome cuidado pois o WhatsApp pode considerar este comportamento como spam e banir a conta. O uso sem autorização da API do WhatsApp, que seria possível envio em maiores quantidades, também pode acarretar no banimento.